# line on side header css with different color

Tags: css

Hello  i need make a heading with side lines but i need one side of the line in color #ef387a and the other side color #1c77bd any can help me to make this? i have make some script for show what i need, but i dont know how make diferent colors for each side, i try diferents ways but without results,but now the code if i have is cleand and correctly only i need change the colors of each side, understand me? i hope can help me guys! thanks!

example:

/ (COLOR:#ef387a)   ......   / (COLOR:#1c77bd )

------------------ MI TITLE -----------------------

here my script

http://dabblet.com/gist/1560674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the background color to the css.

Change the CSS to reflect:

```
h1:before {    
    left: -.5em;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
    background: #ef387a;
    }
h1:after {    
    left: .5em;
    margin: 0 -50% 0 0;
    background: #1c77bd;
    }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3tL5gxaz/1/

Comment: Done bro! thanks for you time! best vibes and happy new year!